# Date-time recorded by mongo-db is different from clientPC (server location is in same region)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime

This is about a different date-time recorded in mongoDb via Node.js.
e.g. the date time recorded is 2022-02-01T13:32:01.967Z,
the actual time is 19:02 for the same date.

Looks like it has recorded GMT. This code will be eventually run on a VPS based in my country. However, at the moment I am running the code on localhost.

below is the code in Node.js

```
/// part of a controller method

  const xDate = new Date();
  console.log('new Date()', xDate);
  // output: 2022-02-01T13:32:01.967Z, actual time 19:02 on same date

  candidate.history.push({
    actionDate: xDate,
    userId: user.acctId,
    userName: user.userName,
    remarks: 'bla bla bla'
  })
  await candidate.save();
```

Any idea how to correct it? In Angular we can set the input field to datetime-local type to save the date/time without timezone. Can we do something similar in Node.js /mongodb? How do I get the correct time stored in mongo?

I have read that MongoDB always stores the timestamp in UTC. Is there any way this can be handled application-wide to handle all date values recd from Mongo in both the below cases:

1. at Node.js levelfor performing some date calculations based on date value recd from Angular?
2. At Angular level for date values recd from Node(as it is from Mongo)

Comment: MongoDB stores timestamps in UTC. if you want to convert to a local timezone, do it in the app, after loading data from the db.

Comment: The timestamp is still correct, though. It's just not localized.

Comment: Is there any way this can be handled application-wide to convert all date values to local timezone, without doing it in each and every method where date is being handled?

Comment: check here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/

Comment: Use a 3rd party library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) or [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/installation). Usually localized timestamp can be defined in your application - it depends on the application, of course.

Comment: This was very simple to handle.  In angular, I just recreated date value using ```new Date(savedDateInMongo)``` and it displayed the correct local date time.